# How to get integer resource array through typed-array?

Tags: android, arrays, android-custom-view

I have declared following declare-stylables in attr.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="SideSpinnerAttrs">
    <attr name="stringValues" format="reference" />
    <attr name="iconIDs" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Array of resource icons in array.xml:

```
<integer-array name="spinnerIcons">
    <item>@drawable/ic_attachment_black_24dp</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_audiotrack_black_24dp</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_slideshow_black_24dp</item>
</integer-array>
```

I would like to call and set those icons from array to an imageView:

```
    private void readSpinnerIcons(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray icons=context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.SideSpinnerAttrs);

    int id=icons.getResourceId(R.styleable.SideSpinnerAttrs_iconIDs,0);
    int[] i=getResources().getIntArray(id);
    spinner_icon.setBackgroundResource(i[0]);
}
```

But, array "int[] i", is empty. Why?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
         <integer-array name="IntArray">
              <item>2</item>
              <item>8</item>
              <item>10</item>
              <item>16</item>
         </integer-array>
    </resources>
```

You can use this

```
Resources r = getResources();
int[] bases = r.getIntArray(R.array.IntArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
int id=icons.getResourceId(R.styleable.SideSpinnerAttrs_iconIDs,0);
```

The first argument is not the `Styleable` resource id, but rather the index of the TypedArray containing the resource id. Since you're not providing a valid index, `id` will always be the default value you're using as the 2nd argument, which means your `int[]` array `i` will always be empty.

Also, make sure you always call recycle() once you're done using a `TypedArray`. Use the following:

```
private void readSpinnerIcons(Context context) {
    TypedArray icons = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {R.styleable.SideSpinnerAttrs});
    int id = icons.getResourceId(0, 0);
    int[] i = getResources().getIntArray(id);
    spinner_icon.setBackgroundResource(i[0]);
    icons.recycle();
}
```